# Formik with Material Ui Re-Renders like crazy

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, formik, formik-material-ui

This is my first post therefore apologies in advanced.

Hello there,
i was working on a company project using Material Ui v5 with Formik@2.2.9
and i was using the Formik's official [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/formik/formik/tree/master/examples/with-material-ui?from-embed) for Material-Ui integration as a baseline for my code.

here are my observations:

1. Even on Official Example: every keystroke on Text Field Trigger re-render 4 Time (FOR EACH WORD)
2. Re-render like these was causing significant slowdowns on Firefox.
3. Chrome was also affected but Chrome was hanging less.
4. i triple checked my code, it was fine.

[here is a image of the re-rendering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpd3v.png)

as you can see i only added "1" to the email field and it triggered 4 re-renders

**How to reproduce**
go to official example place a console log to detect re-render
or
you can try yourself from [link to my fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-microservice-jbndpz?file=/index.js)

**let me know if it is really a issue from formik or its something else?**
**and How can i improve the performance?**

Comment: This is how formik works by default, but you can reduce the number of renders with some other strategies. Is this the only thing you want to know? If it's an issue or if it's the standard behavior?

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure if it's a standard behavior or a bug. but my main concern is the performance. its just slows down the website.

as you are saying if its a standard behavior then i should move on to react-final-form, at lease i'll not face any performance issues.

Comment: You can use any library you want. You only asked if it's an issue or not, so I only said it's definitely not an issue. But there's ways of increasing the perfomance issue and not rendering 4 times while using formik

Comment: yes. i need the workaround for it, i tried but still didn't find any solution.